# Dynamically Clone or create the row only if the first row data is filled and the dropdown state is change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below code Creates the html table and creates a static row and then on button click the same row is created but my problem is i don't want to

1. create or clone the row on button click
2. the row should be created on if the data of textbox(s) of that row are not null  and the select value is not test then a new row needs to be created beneath that row .

[Js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JpquX/21/)

HTML:

```
<div id="results"></div>

<input id="buttonclck" type="button" value="button"/>
```

JS:

```
    $('#results').append('<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="productanddates" class="border"> <tr><td> <input type="text" name="to1" id="to1" value="" /> </td> <td> <select name="Phonenumberdd1" id="Phonenumberdd1"> <option value="test">test </option> <option value="demo">demo</option></select></td> <td>   <input type="text" name="renewal_by1" id="renewal_by1" />  </td>   <td> <input type="text" name="Renivaul_to1" id="Renivaul_to1" value="" /> </td></TR></TABLE>'
);


    $('#buttonclck').on('click', function () {
        var lastRow = $('#productanddates').closest('#productanddates').find("tr:last-child");

        var cloned = lastRow.clone();
        cloned.find('input, select').each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            var regIdMatch = /^(.+)(\d+)$/;
            var aIdParts = id.match(regIdMatch);
            var newId = aIdParts[1] + (parseInt(aIdParts[2], 10) + 1);

            $(this).attr('id', newId);
            $(this).attr('name', newId);
        });

cloned.find("input[type='text']").val('');
        cloned.insertAfter(lastRow);
    });
```

Comment: i dont understand your goal

Comment: @carlodenaro , oops sorry :( , want to eliminate the Button, say i want to create a new row it  is created by clicking on button right now ,but i want the new row to be created if all the text box values are filled of the first row then a row to be created as it is created now on button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this approach

- When a form element is focused check and save current state of all form elements
- Once content of a form element changes set `data-filled` to `true` for that element, see if all elements on current row have `data-filled` set.
- If `data-filled` is set, if that row's `data-done` attribute is not set to true then add new row and set rows `data-done` attribute to true
- Since all the rows are added dynamically, delegated events would be used.

```js
$('#results').append('<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="productanddates" class="border"> <tr><td> <input type="text" name="to1" id="to1" value="" /> </td> <td> <select name="Phonenumberdd1" id="Phonenumberdd1"> <option value="test">test </option><option value="test2">test 2</option></select></td> <td>   <input type="text" name="renewal_by1" id="renewal_by1" />  </td>   <td> <input type="text" name="Renivaul_to1" id="Renivaul_to1" value="" /> </td></TR></TABLE>'
);

    $('#results').on('focus', ':input', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').filter(function() { 
            return !$(this).data('saved'); 
        })
        .find(':input').each(function() {
            $(this).data('value', this.value);
            $(this).closest('tr').data('saved', true);
        });
    })
    .on('input change', ':input', function() {
        $(this).data('filled', this.value != $(this).data('value'))
        var tr  = $(this).closest('tr');
            all = tr.find(':input'),
            fld = all.filter(function() {
                return $(this).data('filled');
            });
        if( all.length == fld.length ) {
            if( !tr.data('done') ) {
                $('#buttonclck')[0].click();
                tr.data('done', true);
            }
        } else {
            if( tr.data('done') ) {
                tr.next('tr').remove();
                tr.data('done', false);
            }
        }
    });

 $('#buttonclck').on('click', function () {
     var lastRow = $('#productanddates').closest('#productanddates').find("tr:last-child");

     var cloned = lastRow.clone();
     cloned.find('input, select').each(function () {
         var id = $(this).attr('id');

         var regIdMatch = /^(.+)(\d+)$/;
         var aIdParts = id.match(regIdMatch);
         var newId = aIdParts[1] + (parseInt(aIdParts[2], 10) + 1);

         $(this).attr('id', newId);
         $(this).attr('name', newId);
     });

        cloned.find("input[type='text']").val('');
     cloned.insertAfter(lastRow);
 });
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>

<input id="buttonclck" type="button" class="hide" value="button"/>
```

Comment: @ PeterKA , i have a quick question if u dont mind can the below all row be removed if the above text box has a value is null or the select value is test

Comment: Code has been updated. Please let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: need some help can i have your some of the time

Comment: i have a issue here the problem is that a new row is not created until some data is not typed manually am trying to produce the value to some of the textbox on dropdown change but still on the dropdown change the values are filled on text boxes and still the row is not created hear is the demo   http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/1/

Comment: Would you like to ask a new question please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88212/discussion-between-pauli-and-peterka).

Comment: do u want me to ask a new question ??

Comment: Yes please. I'd be glad to help.

Comment: Check out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274320/html-create-a-new-row-if-data-is-present-in-the-textbox-without-focus-also-and-o

Answer (score 0):

Try this - work only for first input (is example)

http://jsfiddle.net/xegnt0uh/1/

```
$('#buttonclck').on('click', function () {
    var lastRow = $('#productanddates').closest('#productanddates').find("tr:last-child");

//eg. if input[0] value isnt ""
if(lastRow.find('input')[0].value !== "") {

    var cloned = lastRow.clone();
    cloned.find('input, select').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        var regIdMatch = /^(.+)(\d+)$/;
        var aIdParts = id.match(regIdMatch);
        var newId = aIdParts[1] + (parseInt(aIdParts[2], 10) + 1);

        $(this).attr('id', newId);
        $(this).attr('name', newId);
    });

    cloned.find("input[type='text']").val('');
    cloned.insertAfter(lastRow);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I renamed select to `selectbox`

```
$('#buttonclck').on('click', function () {
        var lastRow = $('#productanddates').find("tr:last-child");
        var selectLastRow = lastRow.find('select[name=selectbox]').val(); // <-- add this select value

        if(typeof selectLastRow !== 'undefined' && selectLastRow != '' && selectLastRow != 'test') { // <-- add this condition

        var cloned = lastRow.clone();
        cloned.find('input, select').each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            var regIdMatch = /^(.+)(\d+)$/;
            var aIdParts = id.match(regIdMatch);
            var newId = aIdParts[1] + (parseInt(aIdParts[2], 10) + 1);

            $(this).attr('id', newId);
          //  $(this).attr('name', newId); // REMOVE THIS BECAUSE WE FIND IN TR
        });

        cloned.find("input[type='text']").val('');
        cloned.insertAfter(lastRow);
    }
    });
```

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JpquX/22/)

**EDIT 

-------**

> if all the condition are met a same new row to be created below that
>   so on

so set number of empty inputs

```
var emptyInputs = lastRow.find('.input').filter(function () { return this.value.length == 0; }).length;
```

and modify condition like below

```
if(typeof selectLastRow !== 'undefined' 
   && selectLastRow != '' 
   && selectLastRow != 'test'
   && emptyInputs == 0
) { ....
```

[DEMO2 JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JpquX/24/)

Comment: Thanks everything is perfect but can't the new row be created without button click say if all the condition are met a same new row to be created below that so on