# HTML Create a new row if data is present in the textbox without focus also and on second row drop down does not provide data only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a issue here the problem is that a new row is not created until some data is not typed manually am trying to produce the value to some of the textbox on dropdown change but still on the dropdown change the values are filled on text boxes and still the row is not created **and on second row the second row the dropdown does not provides the data on change also**

```js
$('#results').append('<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="productanddates" class="border"> <tr><td> <input type="text" name="to1" id="to1" value="" /> </td> <td> <select class="dd" name="Phonenumberdd1" id="Phonenumberdd1"> <option value="test">test </option><option value="test2">test 2</option></select></td> <td>   <input type="text" name="renewal_by1" id="renewal_by1" />  </td>   <td> <input type="text" name="Renivaul_to1" id="Renivaul_to1" value="" /> </td></TR></TABLE>');

$('#results').on('focus', ':input', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').filter(function() {
        return !$(this).data('saved');
      })
      .find(':input').each(function() {
        $(this).data('value', this.value);
        $(this).closest('tr').data('saved', true);
      });
  })
  .on('input change', ':input', function() {
    $(this).data('filled', this.value != $(this).data('value'))
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    all = tr.find(':input'),
      fld = all.filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('filled');
      });
    if (all.length == fld.length) {
      if (!tr.data('done')) {
        $('#buttonclck')[0].click();
        tr.data('done', true);
      }
    } else {
      if (tr.data('done')) {
        tr.next('tr').remove();
        tr.data('done', false);
      }
    }
  });

$('#buttonclck').on('click', function() {
  var lastRow = $('#productanddates').closest('#productanddates').find("tr:last-child");

  var cloned = lastRow.clone();
  cloned.find('input, select').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    var regIdMatch = /^(.+)(\d+)$/;
    var aIdParts = id.match(regIdMatch);
    var newId = aIdParts[1] + (parseInt(aIdParts[2], 10) + 1);

    $(this).attr('id', newId);
    $(this).attr('name', newId);
  });

  cloned.find("input[type='text']").val('');
  cloned.insertAfter(lastRow);
});


$('#productanddates tr').on('change', '.dd', function(e) {
  var data = "dummy data";
  $(this).closest('td').prev().find('input').val(data);
  $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').val(data);
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>

<input id="buttonclck" type="button" class="hide" value="button" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve that you want to trigger `input` or `change` event once you programmatically change the value of any of the input elements:

```
$(this).closest('td').prev().find('input').val(data).trigger('input');
$(this).closest('td').next().find('input').val(data).trigger('input');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/3/)

Here is some explanation to help you in the future:

```
$('#productanddates tr').on('change','.dd', function(e) {
//  ^The selector you put here must refer to an element that is in the DOM
//   when the page loads. The `tr` element does not exist at page load
//   and therefore is not a valid element to use
```

> `$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+`
>   `$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+`
>   `$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+`

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Here is what should work:

```
$('#results').on('change','.dd', function(e) {
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/4/)

Comment: Thanks but did u see on the other issue i told on second row the dropdown does not provide the data to the textboxs

Comment: @Pauli, you're all set now.

Comment: @ PeterKA , do you have any idea about saving the same in the sqlite database?

Comment: Would suggest reading up on ajax and whatever scripting language your server supports.

Comment: am not saving the data on server this is a phonegap application which where the data is locally stored in the local sqlite database

Comment: Hello peter need help can i have some of your time if you don't mind

Comment: need little help on same problem of trigger hear i have added condition on dropdown change new row is not created

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a new question? You're free to refer back to this.

Comment: Hi  i have posted a new question can you help me on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559055/on-select-change-disable-option-if-selected-previois-and-create-a-clone-row-not