# On Select change Disable option if selected previois and create a clone row not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable a select option if selected on a previous row say my html table creates a row if the value of a last rows text box are filled and select is changed what i was trying to do was if the select option is selected before then on new row created the select option should be disabled when i add the code of disable then the new row is not created.

[Demo Fiddle with select code](http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/37/)

[Demo Fiddle with out select code](http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/38/)

```
$('#results').append('<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="productanddates" class="border"> <tr><td> <input type="text" name="to1" id="to1" value="" /> </td> <td> <select class="dd" name="Phonenumberdd1" id="Phonenumberdd1"> <option value="test">test </option><option value="test1">test1 </option><option value="test2">test 2</option></select></td> <td>   <input type="text" name="renewal_by1" id="renewal_by1" />  </td>   <td> <input type="text" name="Renivaul_to1" id="Renivaul_to1" value="" /> </td></TR></TABLE>');

//*******the select code if this is removed all works fine******?//
setTimeout(function () {
    var $selects = $('select');
    $selects.on('change', function () {


        $("option", $selects).prop("disabled", false);
        $selects.each(function () {
            var $select = $(this),
                $options = $selects.not($select).find('option'),
                selectedText = $select.children('option:selected').text();
            $options.each(function () {
                if ($(this).text() == selectedText) $(this).prop("disabled", true);
            });
        });
    });

    $selects.eq(0).trigger('change');

}, 99);



$('#results').on('focus', ':input', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').filter(function () {
        return !$(this).data('saved');
    })
        .find(':input').each(function () {
        $(this).data('value', this.value);
        $(this).closest('tr').data('saved', true);
    });
})
    .on('input change', ':input', function () {
    $(this).data('filled', this.value != $(this).data('value'))
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    all = tr.find(':input'),
    fld = all.filter(function () {
        return $(this).data('filled');
    });
    if (all.length == fld.length) {
        if (!tr.data('done')) {
            $('#buttonclck')[0].click();
            tr.data('done', true);
        }
    } else {
        if (tr.data('done')) {
            tr.next('tr').remove();
            tr.data('done', false);
        }
    }
});

$('#buttonclck').on('click', function () {
    var lastRow = $('#productanddates').closest('#productanddates').find("tr:last-child");

    var cloned = lastRow.clone();
    cloned.find('input, select').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        var regIdMatch = /^(.+)(\d+)$/;
        var aIdParts = id.match(regIdMatch);
        var newId = aIdParts[1] + (parseInt(aIdParts[2], 10) + 1);

        $(this).attr('id', newId);
        $(this).attr('name', newId);
    });

    cloned.find("input[type='text']").val('');
    cloned.insertAfter(lastRow);
});


$('#results').on('change', '.dd', function (e) {
    var data = "dummy data";
    $(this).closest('td').prev().find('input').val(data).trigger('input');
    $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').val(data).trigger('input');
});
```

Comment: Is the objective to disable `option` elements that have been selected in previous rows? What should happen when all values/options of the select have been used up?

Comment: That will be the end of that no more selection a last blank row will be left blank

Comment: To be informed that there will be no more auto increment of rows of all select are selected up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code, executed once a new row is added, should iterate through the previous rows and disable in the new row values of select that have already been used:

```
    var prevRows = cloned.siblings();
    cloned.find('select option').each(function(index,option) {
        prevRows.each(function(i,tr) {
            option.value !== $('select', tr).val() || $(option).prop('disabled',  true);
        });
    });
```

**DEMOS**

- [**DEMO 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/99pvwypp/41/)
- [**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/99pvwypp/40/)
- [**DEMO 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/99pvwypp/39/)

Comment: Perfect  but i dint get why have you added multiple demo s

Comment: Just shows you other ways of doing the same thing but the first is the most optimized one.

Comment: sure thanks  i have a small issue that is say you selected test1 in first row and filled all the data then on new row created then there  test1 is disabled fine and when you go to first row and change to test2 and as i have selected test2 on second row so both will be same

Comment: and one more issue is if i select test2 then it should be disabled on first row

Comment: The code snippet that I supplied is run on the new row, iterating through the other rows to disable options that have already been selected. I am confident that you can add similar code to disable options in rows other than the new one. Give it a try :-)